# LyX, Biblatex, ClassicThesis: How can I avoid line breaks in citations?

Tags: biblatex, lyx, citing, classicthesis

I suspect I am not the only person with this problem but I cannot find any solution for it:

I am writing a thesis using LyX and the classicthesis template.
I manage my bibliography with Zotero but export the bib-file so I can use the LyX dialogue for inserting citations rather than the Zotero-LyZ-plugin.
I use biblatex and its author-year-style for citations.

At the end of the line my citations break in a very ugly way.

```
Freqently, I get something like (Author, Year, p.
    178). It looks especially ugly when it occurs at the end of a paragraph,
    say, like this (Author, Year, p. 206
    f.).

If it has to break, I would not mind a citation breaking like this (Author,
Year, p. 23).
```

What is important to me is that the next line does not start with just a few integers or an abbreviation, followed by a parenthesis.

I am pretty new to LaTeX, BibLaTeX, LyX, and the classicthesis template but way too far along with the thesis to switch to a different combo. (I think.)

I am not sure how to produce a MWE, as due to the classicthesis template all of the options are scattered over several files and my document is a LyX file.

What I would like to know is whether this line break issue is normal behavior. Is the only other option the citation extending into the margin, using an mbox?

If, despite the lacking MWE, someone could point me to a way to make citations break at nicer places, I would be extremely grateful.

Also, a hint on how to create an MWE would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: is this from `\cite[p. 23]{foo}` or is the page number in the bib file? in either case you could use `p.~23` (sorry I have no idea about lyx)

Comment: Thank you! That does help a bit. I can just put a tilde where I would normally put spaces. It also works in the LyX dialogue, except for the space before `p~23)`. I cannot prevent it from breaking between `(Author, Year,` and `p.~23)` this way.

Comment: You should allow `biblatex` to break somewhere (if reluctantly) in your citation label, withing "p. 23" looks odd and is in fact suppressed by `biblatex` (that works only if you let `biblatex` add the "p."/"pp." prefix automatically as in `\cite[23]{sigfridsson}`, not if you give it yourself as in `\cite[23]{sigfridsson}`, the former is the preferred way). In theory it would be possible to disallow breaking after the year, but that could lead to overfull boxes pretty quickly.